# Search in all the versions of a file of git repo

Tags: git, full-text-search, atlassian-sourcetree

I have a folder on my computer which is a git repo.
This folder contains a file (amongst many other) named `fileA`

I would like to search a string `str` in the content of all (or of a subset of all) the committed versions `fileA`.

Is it possible?

I am not an expert in git, I use [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com) to manage the repo.

I'm interested by any solution. For instance, a solution using [GitLab](https://gitlab.com) ou [GitHub](https://github.com) is fine for me.

---

## A solution with SourceTree

A solution *via* a command to execute in the terminal has been given .

Is there a solution with SourceTree?

Answer (score 2):

See [grep-all](https://github.com/GitAlias/gitalias/blob/1899d64721cbffafc2a9f7fd3a63e2032a04f9ef/gitalias.txt#L314) alias:

```
grep-all = !"f() { git rev-list --all | xargs git grep \"$@\"; }; f"
```

The alias lists all revisiosn in all branches with `git rev-list --all` and runs `git grep` on every revision.

To adapt it for grepping one file do

```
git rev-list --all | xargs -I% git --no-pager grep -F -e str % -- fileA
```

PS. Full disclosure: I am a contributor and reviewer in the linked repository.

Comment: Thanks. Should I execute this command directly on the folder/repo? Thanks

Comment: Also, could you add the command to search `str` in all the revisions of the repo? Thanks

Comment: Yes, run the command in the worktree directory. The command runs `git grep` on all revisions; all revisions of all branches are listed with `git rev-list --all`.

Answer (score 0):

For a "graphical" solution using SourceTree, I guess you will have to open a new issue with a *new feature* request on their Jira tracking webpage:

https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREEWIN